# I want to create a Vector to hold classes

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm very confused about making a vector to hold classes.

If I wanted to hold a bunch of data in a single vector like the example below, then have the data written in a class member function, and able to be called out and used by other functions.

Where do I stick the vector declaration? please help!

```
#include <vector>

class Card
{
   public:
    int suit;
    int rank;
    Card::Card(int suit, int rank);
    Function();
};

vector<Card> cards;

int main()
{
}

Card::Function()
{
    for loop...
    Card cardz(i, i);
    cards.push_back(cardz);
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples around, e.g. http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov  im using Visio express C++, and i dont want to mess with linux, especially since im already confused, thanks though!

Comment: Programming is actually infinitely easier and less complicated in linux

Comment: The only thing definitively wrong with the definition of `cards` is that it should be `std::vector`, not `vector`. You might want to make `cards` a static data member of the class `Card`, I'm not sure. Also, your constructor `Card::Card` should just be `Card`, and `Function` needs a return type. Which specific compiler error is it that's troubling you?

Comment: @Falmarri everything with linux is easier, i just have to make sure it works on windows

Comment: @Steve Jessop i use "using namespace std" which enables me to not use std:: scopes. right?

Comment: @TimothyTech: Yes, that would do it. I don't see it in the code above, though. It's usually best to ask a question about the code you post, not about some other code that you have on your PC that none of us has seen :-)

Comment: STL is the same (according to the C++ library standard) on Windows and Linux. If you can't be bothered reading a web page, sorry, we can't help you.

Comment: @TimothyTech Reminds me of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390820/placing-a-class-object-inside-a-vector. Asked by you only six hours ago. Eh?

Comment: Since no namespace was defined, you should probably add *std::*  before vector, like the following: std::vector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that you're stretching the bounds of what a `Card` object should do. May I suggest the following layout? First defines a *single* card.

```
class Card {
  public:
    Card(int s, int r)
    : suit(s), rank(r)  {
      // Initialize anything else here
    }

  private:
    int suit, rank;
};
```

Next, define an object which holds a `vector` of cards and manipulates them. Let's call it `Deck`

```
class Deck {
  public:
    Deck();

  private:
    vector <Card> cards;
};
```

Now, in your `Deck` class, you can initialize the collection of cards as you see fit.

```
Deck::Deck() {
  for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
    for (int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++) {
      cards.push_back(Card(suit, rank));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple options here.  Closer to what you have written, use an `extern` declaration in the header file:

```
// something.h
extern vector<Card> cards;

// something.cpp
vector<Card> cards;
```

Or if it makes sense for this vector to "belong" to `class Card` (but there's still only one of them), you can make it a `static` member:

```
// Card.h
class Card {
  // ...
  static void init_cards();
  static vector<Card> cards;
};

// Card.cpp
vector<Card> Card::cards;
```

The `static` member can be `public` or `private` like any other member.  If it is `public`, any code which is not in a `Card` method which uses `cards` will have to call it `Card::cards`.

Either way, you have to figure out how to initialize it with the contents you want....

Comment: One needs to be aware of what the vector might do with the items it contains - especially copying.