# operator overloading + sign, for class members

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an issue, i need to add two class members using a operator overload. issue also is that the members i need to add are strings.. i tried using stringstream but i didnt seem to work, an infinite loop of errors occur. is there a very easy way to turn a string into a integer to add? or at least a way to add two strings to print out the sum

```
class PlayingCard
{
    public:
    char suit;
    string rank;
    PlayingCard operator +();
};

PlayingCard deck[52];
PlayingCard player[10];
PlayingCard dealer[10];
int playerHits = 2;
int dealerHits = 2;

PlayingCard PlayingCard::operator+()
{

    int r1;
    int r2;

    stringstream pr1;
    stringstream pr2;

    string temp1 = player[1].rank;
    string temp2 = player[2].rank;

    pr1 << temp1;
    pr2 << temp2;

    pr1 >> r1;
    pr2 >> r2;

    return(r1 + r2);

}
```

Comment: You realize you're trying to overload the unary plus sign, right? Also, what does it mean to add two playing cards?

Comment: Are you asking how to define an operator for your class? Or are you asking how to convert a string into an integer. Those are totally separate issues, so they should be separate questions. Please be clear about what it is you're having trouble with. What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? (But the string-to-integer question has already been answered here, so please don't ask it again.)

Comment: Are we doing Timothy's homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393603/i-want-to-create-a-vector-to-hold-classes/4393700#4393700 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390820/placing-a-class-object-inside-a-vector Just sayin'...if so, tag as homework please

Comment: Im making a blackjack game, the class holds the suit and number, i need to make the operator add the cards rank, and if it is a black jack win

Comment: @zourtney nah, just trying to find a way to integrate class's, vectors or arrays, and operator overloading.

Comment: @TimothyTech: fair enough, I meant no harm at all. :-) We here are happy to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator+` does not take any parameters and therefore cannot work.

A member `operator+` has to have the following signature:

```
class X {
    X operator+(const X &b);
};
```

A *free* `operator+` needs to look that way:

```
X operator+(const X &a, const X &b);
```

Well, that is one way to go.

I suggest you **get back to the books** ;)

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to overload unary plus -- his declaration is correct for that purpose.

Comment: thank you very mmuch! my books suck! theyre examples are impossible

Answer (score 2):

You might want to first define what you mean by the operation of "*adding two playing cards together.*" Let's say I have the jack of spades and the queen of hearts, physically in my hand. As physical entities, those don't add.

Their rank, however does; we could say `jack + queen => 11 + 12 => 23` if we assign integer values to their ranks. Obviously there is no "23 card". Therefore, adding two `PlayingCard`s together can not reliably return a valid `PlayingCard`.

The question is, would it just be easier to query their `rank` when it is needed? For example:

```
if (card1.rank + card2.rank > 21) {
  // dealer wins
}
```

In this case, there isn't even a for an intermediate `PlayingCard` to be returned -- all we care about is the sum of the `rank`s of `card1` and `card2`.

Sorry, I've deviated from your source a bit...the above is assuming you would store the rank as an `int`, as you had in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393603/i-want-to-create-a-vector-to-hold-classes/4393700#4393700). This method is highly preferable since you *will* be doing mathematical operations on them (like my dumb example above).

Comment: This. Adding cards together makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)?

```
atoi(player[1].rank.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you define the return type as PlayingCard

```
PlayingCard PlayingCard::operator+()
```

But here you return an integer:

```
int r1;
int r2;
// STUFF
return(r1 + r2);
```